# WPF Datagrid some column not selected

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, datagrid

I have a WPF `DataGrid` in a `UserControl` that binds with a caliburn `BindableCollection`. It works like a charm except for 2 columns that sometimes does not select some cell. I tries everything, virtualizing and binding Async. Any suggestion?

Comment: Please give us some code to reproduce this problem.

Comment: I'm sorry, I fixed it. There was a Control not visibile but enabled tv ad interact with the grid...sorry